# object to string array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to convert an object (is declared here as 'obj': object is array, primitive) to a string array.

object can be anything uint[], int16[], etc.

I have been trying to use

```
string[] str = Array.ConvertAll<object, string>((object[])obj, Convert.ToString);
```

The problem occurs when I try to cast the unknown type object into object[].
I have been getting casting error.

One attempt I made, which failed, was using

```
object[] arr = (object[])obj;
```

or

```
IEnumerable<object> list = obj as IEnumerable<object>
object[] arr = (object[])list;
```

I saw postings regarding value type and reference type issue on casting.

Would there be a simple code that can handle casting to object[] regardless of type of object, as long as it is an array ?
I am trying to avoid manual handling of every possible type casting.

Comment: You cannot cast arrays of value types to `object[]`, they're not compatible.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use the fact that every array implements `IEnumerable`:

```
string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)obj).Cast<object>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                 .ToArray();
```

This will box primitives appropriately, before converting them to strings.

The reason the cast fails is that although arrays of *reference* types are covariant, arrays of *value* types are not:

```
object[] x = new string[10]; // Fine
object[] y = new int[10]; // Fails
```

Casting to just `IEnumerable` will work though. Heck, you could cast to `Array` if you wanted.

Comment: Why is there a need to box primitives?

Comment: @Douglas: Because you can't cast a primitive type array to `object[]`, and we don't know the type beforehand.

Comment: It works even without cast to `IEnumerable`, why do you want to cast it esplicity ?

Comment: @Tigran: It won't work if `obj` is declared as just `object`, which is the way I read the question.

Comment: ah ok, you mean that `object[]` is presented like single `object`.

Comment: I don’t think you need to cast. `objs.Select(obj => obj.ToString())` simply requires that `objs` implements `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` has a `ToString()` method.

Comment: Thanks Jon..and how come casting using IEnumerable<object> list = obj as IEnumerable<object>; makes list equals to null ?

Comment: @JP_medevice: Because it implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: This works well, unless `obj` is passed from VBScript and contains an element with value Empty. In this case an exception with message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." is raised.

Comment: @DeveloperWebs: Or more idiomatically in C#, a null reference. But yes, I don't tailor every answer to cope with null references unless there's something in the question suggesting it should be taken into account.

Answer (score 17):

If it's always a collection of some type (array, list, etc ...) then try casting back to plain old `System.Collections.IEnumerable` and go from there

```
string[] str = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)obj)
  .Cast<object>()
  .Select(x => x.ToString())
  .ToArray();
```

Here is a more thorough implementation that handles non-collections as well

```
static string[] ToStringArray(object arg) {
  var collection = arg as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
  if (collection != null) {
    return collection
      .Cast<object>()
      .Select(x => x.ToString())
      .ToArray();
  }

  if (arg == null) {
    return new string[] { };
  }

  return new string[] { arg.ToString() };
}
```

Answer (score -3):

my example:

```
   public class TestObject
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        public string Property2 { get; set; }

        public string Property3 { get; set; }
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestObject> testObjectList = new List<TestObject>
        {
            new TestObject() { Property1 = "1", Property2 = "2", Property3 = "3" },
            new TestObject() { Property1 = "1", Property2 = "2", Property3 = "3" },
            new TestObject() { Property1 = "1", Property2 = "2", Property3 = "3" }
        };

        List<string[]> convertedTestObjectList = testObjectList.Select(x => new string[] { x.Property1, x.Property2, x.Property3 }).ToList();
    }
```