# Convert object to array type

Tags: c#

I am passing an array as an object in a web method.How can I convert object to an array in web method

```
public static string sample(object arr)
{
    string[] res= (string[])arr; //convertion object to string array
    return "";
}
```

I getting error like this

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   Flair.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Have a look in your debugger at the variable arr and check what type it is

Comment: By using `Type x=arr.GetType()` the value x getting as `object[]`

Comment: object[] != string[]

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745542/object-to-string-array

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
public static string sample(object arr)
{

    object[] res= arr as object[];
    if (res != null)
    {
        string[] sRes = res.OfType<string>().ToArray();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplest method:

```
public static string[] Convert(object input)
{
  return input as string[];
}
```

But You have to validate input if you can cast that way, or cast to array of objects and call ToString() on each element

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
public static string sample(object arr)
{
    string[] res = arr as string[]; //convertion object to string array
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you downcast you need to check :

```
public static string sample(object arr)
{
    string[] res=   arr as string[];  
   if (res!=null)
       {
            //ok to continue
       }
   else
      {
         //arr is not string[]
      }
    return "";
}
```

Try to avoid `(string[])arr` unless you're 100% sure that `arr` is `string[]`