# Avoid changing the state of a variable when making use of 'Session' in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to save the result of a calculation (assigned to variable 'ans') for a second request. To do so, I use Session.
Even though it worked in the first request, when I want to call the variable in a second request (else-Statement) the following error occurs :"*Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'*"

Does the state of the variable change through saving it to /accessing it from Session?

The format of 'ans' and 'ansTemp' for the second request is both times tuple of 5 items.

```
private Dictionary<string,int> DoCalculation(CalculatorModel model)
{
        var ansTemp = Session["ANS"];
        Dictionary<string, int> calculatedValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        if (ansTemp == null)
        {
            if (model != null)
            {
                Class1 clsOne = new Class1(pathToLib, pathToPyFile);
                try
                {
                    var ans = clsOne.CallFunction("first_chart", rootPythonDir, model.age);

                    //Session.Add("ANS", ans);
                    Session["ANS"] = ans;
                    var assetAllocationCategory = ans[1];

                 }
                 catch (Exception ex) { }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             var ans = ansTemp;
             var assetAllocationCategory = ans[1];
         }
}
```

Comment: `var ansTemp = Session["ANS"];` assigned `object` to `ansTemp` which in turn you are assigning to `ans` by `var ans = ansTemp;` so `ans` is also object. Now object type does not support indexing by using `[]` that's why you are seeing this error.  So you need to convert `ansTemp` to the proper type by `var ansTemp = Session["ANS"] as whateverTypeYouWantItToBe`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert object to array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874146/convert-object-to-array-type)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Defining ansTemp as a **dynamic** instead of **var** when accessing the Session["ANS"] solved the problem.