# Object returned from FieldInfo.GetValue cannot be cast to Array

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I'm working in a PCL (Profile7), and I've got an issue where the object returned from `fieldInfo.GetValue(myItem)` cannot be cast to an array.

I get a cast exception on a direct cast and (obviously) `null` when using `As`

[image]

how do I cast this object to a collection?

*note: I have no idea what the **type** is as I don't have access to it. It's internal to the library I'm consuming*

Comment: did you try `IEnumerable`?

Comment: If you want to know what the declared type is, check `fi.FieldType`.  If you want to know the runtime type, call `GetType()` on the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the type of the `dynamicProperties` object, it's not visible in the debugger screenshot that you showed. Most likely it's a `List<>` of some sort.

The cast you attempt only succeeds if it's an array of reference types (e.g. `string[]` or `object[]`, it will fail if the type is a struct, as illustrated in this question: [object to string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745542/object-to-string-array)

In any case, the `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces are covariant, you could try casting to `IEnumerable<object>`, or if you need more information such as count or indexer access, try one of the other interfaces.

Comment: I think the "covariant" comment pointed me in the right direction. The type is `List<SomeInaccessibleObject>` but casting to `List<object>` would yield the same result as above. Turns out casting to `IEnumerable<object>` succeeds.

Comment: Once you have an `IEnumerable`, you can create any collection class you want by passing it as a constructor argument, e.g. `var list = new List<object>(myEnumerable)`.